# Django Piston issue - "oauth_user_auth() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Tags: django, django-piston, django-authentication

I am having a few problems setting up Django Piston. I have managed to get as far as generating authentication via the oauth_client.py sample shown here (http://github.com/clemesha/django-piston-oauth-example). When I run "python oauth_client.py" i am taken to http://localhost:8000/api/oauth/authorize/?oauth_token=8wm33jeWR92BpsrHjs where I then tick a box to confirm access and then submit the form.

At this point i hit a "oauth_user_auth() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" error. Simple answer, i'm sure, is that the oauth_user_auth method doesnt accept one parameter, but to remove that character i would have to edit a piston file, which i'm a little reticent to do so. Has anyone else come across this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes from the fact that your OAuth consumer does not specify any callback URL. Your call should look like this:
http://localhost:8000/api/oauth/authorize/?oauth_token=8wm33jeWR92BpsrHjs&oauth_callback=http://www.myoauthconsumer.com/receive_authorization/

http://www.myoauthconsumer.com/receive_authorization/ should request an access token if authorization has been granted by the service provider...
[This diagram](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor9) at oauth.net is very helpful for understanding the workflow of the oauth protocol.